# What does Haskell call the Hom Functor/Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

I'd like to use it in my code and would rather not duplicate it, but since it involves only massively generic words like "function" or "composition" I can't find it by searching.

To be completely specific, I'm looking for

```
instance Functor (x->) where
    fmap f p = f . p
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the basic reader (or environment) monad, usually referred to as `((->) e)`.  (This is `(e ->)` written as a partially applied function instead of as a section; the latter syntax is problematic to parse.)  You can get it by importing `Control.Monad.Reader` or `Control.Monad.Instances`.

Comment: Note that `Reader` proper is just a wrapper around `((->) e)`. Also, for the `Applicative` instance, `pure` and `(<*>)` happen to be the **K** and **S** combinators, which is always fun. :]

Comment: Yep, which is why I said "basic reader monad"; the actual Reader monad is some sugar around the basic `((->) e)` construct, and is mostly useful for the `local` mechanism to introduce a subsidiary "scope" for the environment.

Comment: Thank you! "Reader" is one word I did not try searching for.

Comment: It's a rather bizarre choice of name, apparently intended to mirror `Writer` in the research paper which introduced both of them; "environment" is the preferred term these days for discussion, but we're stuck with `Reader` in code for the forseeable future.

Comment: Should have just called it Hom ;)

Comment: Probably, but most of the category theory stuff in Haskell is actually a retcon. :)

Comment: @Owen: Well, if you look at in the context of `do` notation and the computational interpretation, it makes sense as "a computation with access to a read-only environment", and `State` is roughly a combination of `Reader` and `Writer`... so there is a certain logic, but not one that makes sense from the CT angle.

Comment: Additionally, to generalize, a functor is called representable if it's isomorphic to `((->) e)`. Here are some examples. http://covariant.me/notes/rep-functors.html