# How does an environment happen to be a partially applied function, and even a hom functor?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I have seen `Reader` being used to major benefit many times in the wild. *(One notable example would be `stack`, [built around](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/07/the-rio-monad) a straightforward derivative of `Reader` that can inform the user of the sufficiency of its contents on the type level.)* After some thinking, I arrived to an understanding that this benefit is merely on the level of code structure, and, in a sense, all that `Reader` does is supply a parameter, in many places, to a complicated wiring of functions. That is, I came to believe we can always replace a reader that holds some `x` with a lambda abstraction of form `λx. ... x ... x ...`. This seems to align with the [official explanations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#t:MonadReader) that claim:

> ... the partially applied function type (->) r is a simple reader monad ...

However, there is a long way from noting that `Reader` is a way to write down a lambda abstraction piecewise, to claiming that it is a *partially applied function*.

1. Is there a function that is applied, but not partially? It would simply be a value:

   ```
   λ :t id 1
   id 1 :: Num a => a
   λ :t 1
   1 :: Num a => a
   ```
2. Is there a function that is not even partially applied? We'll never know:

   ```
   λ :t fromMaybe
   fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
   λ :t flip maybe id
   flip maybe id :: b -> Maybe b -> b
   ```

Even ignoring this as nitpicking, I would not take on faith that `(->) r` *(why not just write `(r ->)`?)* is exactly and singularly a `Reader` monad. Maybe I could write an instance that typechecks. Maybe it would even obey the laws. As long as I do not *think* of my functions as `Reader`s, as long as I do not have the right intuition, the vision of it, it is as useful to me as the first proof of the Four Colour Theorem. On the other hand, how can I be sure this is the only way of defining a monad on functions? There are several `Monoid`s on `Num`, at least two `Applicative`s on `List`s − would it not be too reckless to consider a function a `Reader` monad alone?

The predicament does not end here. Once I go searching for an answer, I stumble upon an [even more puzzling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6702169/2108477) note: `Reader` happens to be the `hom` functor now, or even a representable functor in general. And the folks from the other end of the spectrum actually know ahead of time that there would be such a construct in Haskell, and even spell its type, the same as it is spelled in the aforementioned official explanations. Now, this is way over my head, but I can parse the definition of `hom` functor from Mac Lane. With some imagination, it can be seen that, granted a function `a -> b` as a morphism in the (supposed) category **Hask**, we may compose it with `id` to obtain... a function `a -> b` again, this time as an element of the set `hom(a, b)`.

Does this connect in any way with some of these morphisms being *partially applied*? Or with the use of `Reader` as option store in `stack`? Can I actually be shown the object and arrow functions of the hom functor **Hask** -> **Set**? *(I shall take an endofunctor **Hask** -> **Hask** as a reasonable approximation.)* Would that be my trusty fellows `pure` and `fmap`?

And, well, how do I actually use `Reader`, after that?

Answer (score 4):

I can't answer all of your questions, but let's start with the easy ones:

> `(->) r` (why not just write `(r ->)`?)

Because the latter is a syntax error in Haskell. You can't use this section syntax on types.

---

> ... claiming that it is a *partially applied function*.

That's not what it's saying. The quote is:

> the partially applied function type `(->) r` is a simple reader monad

It's a partially applied *type*, not a partially applied function. Or in other words, it's parsed like this: ((partially applied) (function type))

The type constructor for function types in Haskell is spelled `->`.

A fully applied function type looks like `r -> a` (or equivalently `(->) r a`), where `r` is the argument type and `a` the result type.

Thus `(->) r` is a partial application of `->` (the function type).

---

If we ignore monad transformers and `ReaderT`, the straightforward definition of `Reader` is:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader (r -> a)

runReader :: Reader r a -> r -> a
runReader (Reader f) x = f x
-- or rather:
runReader :: Reader r a -> (r -> a)
runReader (Reader f) = f
```

or equivalently:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader{ runReader :: r -> a }
```

That is, `Reader` is just a newtype for `->` (a very thin wrapper), with `runReader` for unwrapping.

You can even make `->` an instance of `MonadReader` just by copying the instance for `Reader` and removing all the `Reader` / `runReader` wrapping/unwrapping.

Comment: This is very helpful! Do you know of any other use of this `(->)` type constructor? And what stopped the masterminds behind it from making it infix-readable after they already made it infix-showable?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov I don't understand your comment. You use `->` every time you write a function type. And what do you mean by infix-readable / infix-showable?

Comment: Oh, right. I can use `->` infix, but I can't use it as an infix section. My question, then, is whether there are any other uses of a partially applied `->` type constructor out there, because I never saw one.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov, it is used without arguments in `instance Category (->)` and `instance Arrow (->)`.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov A partially applied `(->)` can be used as the functor parameter to `Cofree`, resulting in a Moore machine: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html